# Angular Select List Value not binding with Static Values

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel

I have the basic markup and js below. I've been searching all day but can't figure out the solution to get the selected option value.

**AngularJS Version:** v1.5.0

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<select  class="form-control" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2" >Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<button ng-click="getValue()">Try</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var MyApp=  angular.module('MyModule', []);
MyApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.getValue = function () {
       console.log($scope.selectedValue);
    }
});
```

**console.log($scope.selectedValue) returns undefined**

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

```
<button ng-click="getValue()">Try</button>
```

to

```
<button ng-click="getValue(selectedValue)">Try</button>
```

and

```
$scope.getValue = function () {
       console.log($scope.selectedValue);
    }
```

to

```
$scope.getValue = function (param) {
       $scope.selectedValue = param;
       console.log($scope.selectedValue);
    }
```